# UIViewController prevent view from unloading

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, memory-management, uiview, uiviewcontroller

When my iPhone app receives a memory warning the views of UIViewControllers that are not currently visible get unloaded. In one particular controller unloading the view and the outlets is rather fatal.

I'm looking for a way to prevent this view from being unloaded. I find this behavior rather stupid - I have a cache mechanism, so when a memory warning comes - I unload myself tons of data and I free enough memory, but I definitely need this view untouched.

I see UIViewController has a method `unloadViewIfReloadable`, which gets called when the memory warning comes. Does anybody know how to tell Cocoa Touch that my view is not reloadable?

Any other suggestions how to prevent my view from being unloaded on memory warning?

Thanks in advance

---

Apple docs about the view life cycle of a view controller says:

> didReceiveMemoryWarning - The default
>   implementation releases the view only
>   if it determines that it is safe to do
>   so

Now ... I override the `didReceiveMemoryWarning` with an empty function which just calls NSLog to let me know a warning was received. However - the view gets unloaded anyway. Plus, on what criteria exactly is decided whether a view is safe to unload ... oh ! so many questions!

Comment: Perhaps you should refactor your design so the pieces that must not be freed are part of a separate persistent object, not part of the view itself.

Comment: Hi David, there's whole hierarchy of views shown on the screen, and I don't want to tear it down and then build it again, while I show a modal viewcontroller on top ... isn't it an overkill ?

Comment: I love the solution provided by @umpo, but guys, this code results in runtime warning like that `MyViewController implementation of -viewDidUnload caused the view to be reloaded. 
This will adversely impact system performance.` - are you just ignoring it or you do something about it?

Comment: @delirus I have 3 apps already using the exact piece of code @umpo posted and I don't get such warning, I'm building towards 4.3

Comment: huh, so it must be me. Thanks for your reply :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What appears to be working for me was to override `setView:` to ignore setting to nil.  It's kludgy, but then, this is a kludgy issue, and this did the trick:

```
-(void)setView:(UIView*)view {
    if(view != nil || self.okayToUnloadView) {
        [super setView:view];
    }
}
```

Comment: wow ... that's what I call "thinking outside the box" thanks a ton, when I roll next update of my apps I'll implement that

Comment: just a notice - I implemented this - 3 apps using it now on the App store, for me the solution works fine

Comment: the problem with this is that the viewDidUnload method still gets called, which can confuse your code if you're not careful.  I suspect that's why some people are seeing the warnings about adverse performance.

Comment: Could you give more details as to your use of `self.okayToUnloadView`?

Answer (score 15):

According to the docs, the default implementation of [didReceiveMemoryWarning:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/didReceiveMemoryWarning) releases the view if it is safe to do (ie: superview==nil).

To prevent the view from being released you could override didReceiveMemoryWarning: but in your implementation *do not call* `[super didReceiveMemoryWarning]`.  That's where the view is released by default (if not visible).

The default didReceiveMemoryWarning releases the view by calling `[viewcontroller setView:nil]`, so you could override that instead.

Comment: Overriding didReceiveMemoryWarning didn't have any affect for me. Overriding setView makes the debug console complain a whole bunch about how it's going to adversely affect performance. Is this something that will keep you out of the app store?

Answer (score 1):

Could it be so simple?

Even though nowhere in the documentation this is mentioned, it seems that if I exclusively retain my view in viewDidLoad, then it does not get released on Memory Warning. I tried with several consecutive warnings in the simulator and all still seem good.

So ... the trick for the moment is "retain" in viewDidLoad, and a release in dealloc - this way the viewcontroller is "stuck" with the view until the time it needs to be released.

I'll test some more, and write about the results

Comment: This trick didn't seem to work for me. Dealloc is called directly so the view is unloaded regardless. I also attempted to use [self retain]; and that just made it endlessly try to dealloc. Not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think any of these ideas work. I tried overriding [didReceiveMemoryWarning], and that worked for some phones, but found one phone unloaded the view BEFORE that method was even called (must have been in extremely low memory or something). Overriding [setView] produces loads of log warnings so I wouldn't risk that by Apple. Retaining the view will just leak that view - it'll prevent crashes but not really work - the view will replaced next time the controllers UI is loaded.

So really you've just got to plan on your views being unloaded any time they're off-screen, which is not ideal but there you go. The best patterns I've found to work with this are immediate commit so your UI is always up-to-date, or copy-edit-copy, where you copy your model to a temporary instance, populate your views and use immediate commit with that instance, then copy the changes back to your original model when the user hits 'save' or whatever.

Comment: for me overriding the setView: method works perfectly, does not produce warnings and I already have 3 apps on the App store using this technique

Comment: Unfortunately that does nothing to address the blank white screen that will greet the user when a modal view is dismissed to reveal an underlying empty view.

Answer (score 1):

Because the accepted solution has problems with `viewDidUnload` still getting called even though the view was blocked from being cleared, I'm using a different though still fragile approach.  The system unloads the view using an `unloadViewForced:` message to the controller so I'm intercepting that to block the message.  This prevents the confused call to `viewDidUnload`.  Here's the code:

```
@interface UIViewController (Private)
- (void)unloadViewForced:(BOOL)forced;
@end

- (void)unloadViewForced:(BOOL)forced {
    if (!_safeToUnloadView) {
        return;
    }
    [super unloadViewForced:forced];
}
```

This has obvious problems since it's intercepting an undocumented message in UIViewController.

progrmr posted an answer above which recommends intercepting `didReceiveMemoryWarning` instead.  Based on the stack traces I've seen, intercepting that should also work.  I haven't tried that route though because I'm concerned there may be other memory cleanup which would also be blocked (such as causing it to not call child view controllers with the memory warning message).

Comment: Where do you specify category for `UIViewController` ? In `.m` file ? For some reason my overloaded `unloadViewForced` never gets called.

Comment: Yeah, in the .m file.

Comment: I haven't checked to see if it stopped working with any recent iOS updates.  Since it's an undocumented API it could have gone away or been renamed.