# Active modal view is forcefully unloaded after memory warning

Tags: iphone, memory-management, uiview, uiviewcontroller, viewdidload

I have a problem with a view being unloaded which is currenlty active and displayed modally using the following code:

```
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myContentController];

[navController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];

[self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
```

After a memory warning this controller has its view unloaded via the unloadViewForced: method. This results in a black screen being displayed to the user.

Does anyone know what criteria unloadViewIfReloadable uses to determine that the view is active? What setup during the display of the modal view can I do to protect it after a memory warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be related: [uiviewcontroller prevent view from unloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965541/uiviewcontroller-prevent-view-from-unloading)

Comment: Thanks for the link Nick. In the end I found another way to prevent the view from being unloaded. I was creating a new nav controller every time the device orientation changed. I used the code sample in the [View Controller Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/BasicViewControllers/BasicViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH101-SW26) to better handle showing an alternative view in landscape mode.