# iPhone: Why does screen go blank after simulate memory warning?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

When I run my app on the simulator, then I go Hardware->Simulate Memory Warning it causes my view to go blank (I just see white). Does anyone know how I can make it NOT do that? -- I don't want an actual memory warning to make my screen blank.

Thanks

Comment: Are you releasing the current view in your view controllers `didrecievememorywarning`?

Comment: no, didreceivememorywarning is untouched. so it just has a [super didreceivememorywarning] in there... although i think i read somewhere that a memorywarning makes the current view nil or something?

Comment: Do you have anything in viewUnload ?

Comment: no, nothing in viewDidUnload. Although I did notice that that method is being called. So I'm assuming something is setting my view to nil. Also, I'm using a navigationcontroller... maybe it has to do with that. hrmph.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue.  I have an application where you're presented a login screen, which pushes under a NavController a main menu.  Every selection in the main menu then pushes a new view controller.  If i get a memory warning when under a menu item, going back to the menu displays a blank view.

This is probably more of masking the symptom than fixing the problem, but by overriding my main menu's `didReceiveMemoryWarning` message with an empty one (so that the super version isn't being called) stopped the view from disappearing.

I like this better than overriding `setView` (as recommeneded [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965541/uiviewcontroller-prevent-view-from-unloading)) because you don't get the pesky performance warning about "-viewDidUnload caused the view to be reloaded."

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue right now and I solved the problem.

In my case I got this lines inside the mainViewController's code:

```
- (void)loadView {
    [super loadView];
}
```

after simulating a memory warning the system call didReceiveMemoryWarning and you can check that viewDidUnload is called immediately after and if you use loadView inside your code the class call it to reload a brand new page that replace your old view.
This cause a blank screen.

So to solve the issue I just commented the three line above.

Comment: I restudied deeply the problem. Basically the issue can be explained with one question: Where we store the model that draw the view? If the answer is nowhere ... the result is a blank page. When the system raise the Memory Warning notification all the viewControllers run the didReceiveMemoryWarning. After it the method viewDidUnload start to clean our objects if implemented. After all the controllers start over calling viewDidLoad and the view go black. If we stored the configuration, i.e. an image in a model the viewDidLoad reload the view otherwise we fall into a blank screen.

Answer (score -1):

bah, it was mainly because I set my navigation controller incorrectly

Comment: What did you set incorrectly? I'm having similar issue, my friend

Comment: Yeah, we're having the same problem and it has stumped everyone.

Comment: Don't just say you solved it and not share with the community