# UIViewController view being unloaded even when visible

Tags: iphone, ios, memory, uiview

I have a view controller A being shown modally over another view controller B within a navigation controller container.  When simulating memory warnings when this view controller A is shown modally, I receive the didReceiveMemoryWarnings message as expected, and then I receive a message viewDidUnload, thereby making my view controller A's view disappear.

This is surprising to me, and I am not sure how to resolve this. Why is viewDidUnload being called, releasing the visible view in the process?

Here is a stack trace in case it helps pinpoint the problem:

> [UIViewController unloadViewForced:] ()
>
> 0x01458535 in -[UIViewController unloadViewIfReloadable] ()
>
> 0x01463eb8 in -[UINavigationController purgeMemoryForReason:] ()
>
> 0x01457b6d in -[UIViewController didReceiveMemoryWarning] ()

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please, see discussion here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965541/uiviewcontroller-prevent-view-from-unloading

Answer (score 1):

According to http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

> Memory Management
>
> Memory is a critical resource in iOS,
>   and view controllers provide built-in
>   support for reducing their memory
>   footprint at critical times. The
>   UIViewController class provides some
>   automatic handling of low-memory
>   conditions through its
>   didReceiveMemoryWarning method, which
>   releases unneeded memory. Prior to iOS
>   3.0, this method was the only way to release additional memory associated
>   with your custom view controller class
>   but in iOS 3.0 and later, the
>   viewDidUnload method may be a more
>   appropriate place for most needs.
>
> When a low-memory warning occurs, the
>   UIViewController class purges its
>   views if it knows it can reload or
>   recreate them again later. **If this
>   happens, it also calls the
>   viewDidUnload method** to give your code
>   a chance to relinquish ownership of
>   any objects that are associated with
>   your view hierarchy, including objects
>   loaded with the nib file, objects
>   created in your viewDidLoad method,
>   and objects created lazily at runtime
>   and added to the view hierarchy.
>   Typically, if your view controller
>   contains outlets (properties or raw
>   variables that contain the IBOutlet
>   keyword), you should use the
>   viewDidUnload method to relinquish
>   ownership of those outlets or any
>   other view-related data that you no
>   longer need.

But I tried to do the same experiment on iphone simulator and the method viewDidUnload  is not called. I think your behavior can take place when really low memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can simulaute low memory warning from simulator by selecting Hardware>> Simulate memory warning.

And from IOS 6 on low memory viewDidUnload won't be called. So you need to manage what all memory can freed by overriding didreceivememory method warning.

It important to understand, after viewDidUnLoad, viewDidLoad again get called. So you need to assume viewDidLoad will get multiple times in ViewController life cycle.

Say you are not using arc, and allocating array, after some time due to low memory viewDidLoad again get called, this time you again create array than it will cause memory leaks.