# UITabBarController memory issue with modal view controllers

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-management, uitabbarcontroller, modalviewcontroller

My ios app is a UITabBarController based application. There are several situations where I need to present a modal view controller inside another modal view controller.

Everything is working good, expect when a memory warning arrives: if I try to dismiss the two modal view controller in order to go back to where I left the tab bar controller this is what I see:
[image]

The selected tab bar controller view is not displayed on the screen.

These are the full steps causing this issue:

- user opens the first view controller (A) which is presented modally from the currently selected tab bar controller.
- user opens another view controller (B) which is presented modally from the view controller A.
- a memory warning arrives and the hidden views are destroyed.
- user closes B which is dismissed modally (animated).
- user closes A which is dismissed modally (animated).
- the selected controller's view is not displayed.

I have no issue if B is never displayed and a memory warning arrives from A.

I also tried to present A from the tab bar controller and not from the selected view controller but nothing has changed.

I have logged the main view events entry point of my tab-bar and feed controller (the current selected controller). The result is surprising:

```
// B is visible on the screen
2012-05-08 15:30:00.563 - Received memory warning.
2012-05-08 15:30:00.563 - viewDidUnload called on tab-bar controller
2012-05-08 15:30:00.564 - viewDidUnload called on feed controller

// user dismisses B controller and A is displayed
2012-05-08 15:30:30.267 - loadView called on feed controller
2012-05-08 15:30:30.268 - viewDidLoad called on feed controller
2012-05-08 15:30:30.274 - loadView called on tab-bar controller
2012-05-08 15:30:30.274 - viewDidLoad called on tab-bar controller

// user dimisses A controller and tab-bar is displayed
2012-05-08 15:30:40.273 - viewWillAppear: called on tab-bar controller
```

As you can see, the tab-bar view (and the feed as well) are restored when B is dismissed.
This is not what I expected to see, indeed the tab-bar view should be restored when dismissing A.

Any ideas?
thanks

Comment: How is your viewcontroller's view created ? in a XIB file ?

Comment: all view controllers I'm using are created programmatically. no nib files. any suspects?

Comment: basically, when a view controller receives an memory warning it destroys his view and `viewDidUnload` gets called. After that, when the view controller becomes active again it should go through `loadView` and `viewDidLoad` again. Try to investigate these methods and see if there's anything fishy.

Comment: Also, this question provides some workaround (which I don't really recommend but you can keep it as last resort :) ) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965541/uiviewcontroller-prevent-view-from-unloading

Comment: thanks @adig. I followed your suggestion and I traced my app behavior as you can see above.